# VS 2010 updates Designer.cs when no changes are made

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

VS 2010 seems to be updating my form's designer.cs file when I open the form in designer view.

For example, say I have a form with a label of type System.Windows.Forms.Label and I had created the label such that the designer file has (auto generated code)

```
this.myLabel.AutoSize = true;
this.myLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F,
System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.myLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(**25, 63**);
this.myLabel.Name = "myLabel";
this.myLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(**101, 13**);
this.myLabel.TabIndex = 1;
this.myLabel.Text = "A simple windows label.";
```

when I close out of designer view and open it again, VS 2010 will *sometimes* alter it to

```
this.myLabel.AutoSize = true;
this.myLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.25F,
System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.myLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(**29, 78**);
this.myLabel.Name = "myLabel";
this.myLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(**124, 17**);
this.myLabel.TabIndex = 1;
this.myLabel.Text = "A simple windows label.";
```

when I've not done anything other than open the file.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: Don't edit designer-generated files. Ever. Use a partial class and put relevant code in that. Now, the question is: does the form *actually* change - that is, do the controls resize unexpectedly - when *no* form adjustments are made? If so, that's a different issue ("form changing control layout on it's own") which is not directly related to the generation of the code file.

Comment: I'm not editing the generated files. I've also not noticed the form _actually_ changing (but the changes are small, so I might just not be able to tell), but I am using version control with a team of developers and that file gets marked as "updated" when I've not actually changed anything and my code reviewer will then see the changes and wonder "why did you move the form elements around?"

Comment: The label is auto-sized. Perhaps a font-size or DPI change is effecting how the designer calculates the layout to persist it? I wouldn't worry about it (unless the layout *is* effected, which needs to be verified either way) .. perhaps just keep an eye on/revert those changes prior to a push.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feature, not a bug.  The form was originally designed on a machine that had its video adapter dots-per-inch setting at 96.  Your machine has a different DPI, 120.  Very easy to change on modern versions of Windows, you picked the 125% (Medium) setting in Control Panel + Display.

A different dpi setting affects the size of the fonts you use.  There's one visible in your code snippet, it is 8.25 points.  One point is 1/72 inch.  So the text was originally 8.25 * 1/72 = 0.114583 inches high.  With the dpi at 96, that's 0.114583 x 96 = 11 pixels.  Note how this also explains why you got the extra 0.25 added to the point size, it made a nice round number.

But now your dpi is 120, the text will be 8.25 x 1/72 x 120 = 14 pixels.  The text got bigger, your control needs to get bigger too or it will clip the text, shearing off the descenders.

This was done automatically when you loaded the form.  The essential properties are AutoScaleMode, set to Font by default.  And AutoScaleDimensions, you'll find it assigned at the top of the InitializeComponent() method.  That's the one that remembered what the original DPI setting was.

This is going to happen on your user's machine as well.  Do make sure that the form auto-scaled properly.  You may have some trouble if you have controls that have a different font size.  And just check the form back into source control so this rescaling doesn't happen again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked the file's history, and I'm the 3rd person to have "altered" it. By your answer, the first guy and I have the same DPI setting, but the second guy has the medium setting. I'm going to ask him to verify for me.

Comment: I asked the guy and he verified that he did have the medium DPI setting when he turned in changes.