# When opening a project main form files are marked as unsaved

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When opening my project in Visual Studio the code- and designer files for the main form are marked as unsaved (marked with a star after the name of the files):
[image: Unsaved]

If I close VS again right away (without making any changes) VS asks if I want to save the changes.
If I first save all items and then close VS the same happen again on next start of VS.

So my questions are:

1: Why are some kind of changes made automatically to the two mentioned files?

2: Which changes could it be?

3: How to get rid of this behaviour, so when I start my project in VS all files appear as saved, as I have not made any changes myself upon that time?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any form of version control with your project? If so, Visual Studio could be converting line endings.

Comment: No, I don't use any version control.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have posted the designer code so I can only guess that you have created the frmMain on a different machine with different graphics options (especially with diffren DPI).

If you could post your code, may be we can guide you better. Otherwise you may have a look at [VS 2010 updates Designer.cs when no changes are made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557352/vs-2010-updates-designer-cs-when-no-changes-are-made) which explains a little bit more about this feature.

Comment: I have never created or run the code on other machines than mine. As far as I know I have never adjusted the dpi of my machine either. Even if I had, wouldn't the "unsaved" state only show up when reopening after having changed the dpi again?

Comment: @JohnSaps, there could be some other reasons for it. If you can look for the difference in saved file, and opened file, it will help solving your problem

Comment: I now did the following: First I took a copy of the file "frmMain.Designer.cs" and renamed it "Before". Then I opened VS, pressed "Save all" and took a new copy of the file "frmMain.Designer.cs" (the changed date of the file had changed). This I renamed "After". By comparing these two with an online tool they were proofed to be identical.